# How can I install Ubuntu on a hard disk portable?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, portable

How can I install `Ubuntu (14.10)` portable on a `hard disk`/`ssd` and use it on multiple computers. 
Should be compatible with all BIOS versions (uefi etc.) **And it should not be the live version of Ubuntu**

I've got 2 windows 8.1 laptops and would be able to boot from Laptop A and save some data in Ubuntu. And then plug in the ssd in Laptop B and read the data etc.

Comment: we need more info on your setup...but I can definitely tell you that you never want to remove the linux-generic kernels...for they will help you connect it to any computer if using as a portable operating system

Comment: @user175999 Edited question.

Comment: So are you trying to read the data from Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: @user175999 I jus want to boot with one ssd on more computers so Ubuntu should be installed portable on an ssd.

Comment: For a better answer, we should move this to chat...

Comment: OK but can I chat on an Android phone :-)

Comment: should be able to

Comment: And how can we start a chat?

Comment: you should have received an invite

Comment: I haven't received an invite can you copy and paste the URL please?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23006/ubuntu-portable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23007/discussion-between-user175999-and-superthomaslab).

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23007/discussion-between-user175999-and-superthomaslab

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install operating system on a portable disk. More info you can find on the web, but the only thing you should know that you really cannot install any OS on a portable disk.

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Well, at least microsoft OSes cannot be installed on portable disks.

Comment: This is no windows forum I want to install Ubuntu portable.

Comment: Then just choose your portable HDD and install your operating system.